# Detect file creation date on iPhone OS?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsfilemanager

I was planning on writing some code whose logic was based upon testing the creation date of a particular file in my app's Documents folder. Turns out, when I call -[NSFileManager attributesOfItemAtPath:error:], NSFileCreationDate isn't one of the provided attributes.

Is there no way to discover a file's creation date?

Thanks.

Comment: Hey Greg -- it's been 2 years, how 'bout an accept? :D

Comment: To be honest, I don't know if your solution fixed my problem! (I can't remember any more.) The problem I was having was not the code to access the creation date; it's that creation date simply wasn't being returned as one of the file attributes.

Comment: LOL, man, you are tough!

Answer (score 8):

The fileCreationDate is indeed part of the dictionary. Here's a method that gets passed a file URI and grabs some of the attributes from the file:

```
- (NSDictionary *) attributesForFile:(NSURL *)anURI {

// note: singleton is not thread-safe
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSString *aPath = [anURI path];

if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:aPath]) return nil;

NSError *attributesRetrievalError = nil;
NSDictionary *attributes = [fileManager attributesOfItemAtPath:aPath
                           error:&attributesRetrievalError];

if (!attributes) {
   NSLog(@"Error for file at %@: %@", aPath, attributesRetrievalError);
   return nil;
}

NSMutableDictionary *returnedDictionary = 
   [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
        [attributes fileType], @"fileType",
        [attributes fileModificationDate], @"fileModificationDate",
        [attributes fileCreationDate], @"fileCreationDate",
        [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedLongLong:[attributes fileSize]], @"fileSize",
    nil];

return returnedDictionary;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [Apple's reference](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/File_Attribute_Keys), `NSFileCreationDate` is available in 2.0+:

> NSFileCreationDate The key in a file
>   attribute dictionary whose value
>   indicates the file's creation date.
>
> The corresponding value is an NSDate
>   object.
>
> Available in iPhone OS 2.0 and later.
>
> Declared in NSFileManager.h.

Comment: I agree it's in the docs...but in practice, when you get file attributes and look all of them, it's not one of the provided attributes. (I'm away from my computer, otherwise I'd list them all here. There are 11; creation date isn't one of them.)

Comment: I should add that this is the case when I'm running on Simulator. I haven't tried it running on the actual phone. I can try that later tonight.

Comment: Bizarre. NSFileManager's attributesOfItemAtPath:error: should return a dictionary with all of these: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/File_Attribute_Keys -- if it's not there then it seems like you're out of luck. It sure should be.